# No interest ever. Just a fee for my end,

Tags: mathematics, rhyme

Need to lend a tenner?

No interest ever.

Just a fee for my end,

A third of what I lend.

Falling short of the fee?

I will lend it to thee!

What do I lend you all together?

Comment: Part of the puzzle here is trying to work out what your words could possibly *mean*.

Comment: @RosieF it has the British lower-class usage of "lend" to mean borrow

Comment: @Grump., _lower-class_, well I'm offended ... :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here goes!

> From the origins of a tenner
>  We have a geometric progressor
>  To 10 we add its third
>  And to this we add its third
>  This continues for infinity
>  With 15 as its affinity
>  And so it's a tenner times three over two
>  As the amount I now owe to you.

Comment: +1 What, it even rhymes! I feel like a caveman sitting here fiddling with my boring formula.